# Spring Data MongoDB - Is there a way to have an implicit timestamp?

Tags: mongodb, kotlin, spring-data-mongodb

Using my MongoDB and Spring Data MongoDB I am currently looking for a timestamp to be visible in the collection documents.

For now the document looks like this:

```
{
 "_id":"f84fd693-e04b-4acb-9390-32ee755c1506",
 "name":"Herbert",
 "age":{"$numberInt":"21"},
 "_class":"com.alemannigame.backend.domain.Character"
}
```

However I'd like to have a `"timestamp": "1988-03-12T02:30:12+00:00"` (example format) in it as well. Is there a way to do so without having to write logic in a Service to actually add a timestamp manually?

I thought about something like:

```
@Document(withTimestamp: true) // this
data class Character(
    @Id
    val id: String,
    val name: String,
    val age: Int
)
```

Could not find anything similar in the interwebs! Nifty solutions are welcome!

Comment: You can try using `java.util.Date` or `java.time.LocalDateTime` for a date field.

Comment: And Spring Data will do the rest? As I said it should be implicit and not defined manually by me.

Comment: There is no such feature in MongoDB. But, if you dont provide the `_id` value, the driver will insert one for you, of type `ObjectId`. [ObjectId](https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/ObjectId/index.html) has a timestamp value, whcih you can extract from it and use it. But, it has only a seconds precision.

Comment: Ah good info. The problem is I want to stick with UUIDs for some reason. As far as I know MongoDB does not provide these by default as ID format

Answer (score 0):

So I found something out about *Lifecycle Events* for Spring Data MongoDB (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mongo.aggregation).

This gave me several interceptors before a document is saved to MongoDB.
It's very straight forward to use. I chose the `onBeforeConvert` hook so I can manipulate my model before it is being saved.

As you can see I added the timestamp of the `event` to my source instance. I like Unix timestamps and since the `event` object already has that ready I reused it.

```
@Component
class MongoSaveInterceptor : AbstractMongoEventListener<Character>() {
    override fun onBeforeConvert(event: BeforeConvertEvent<Character>) {
        val source = event.source
        source.timestamp = event.timestamp
    }
}
```

*When using MongoDB's implicit `ObjectId` (which I do not - I use an own UUID id) I think that `event.timestamp` is used here.*